# Optimizing Wordpress Queries - Removing Group By ID

Tags: wpdb, sql, groupby

I'm looking to transform a few queries that I'm running through get_posts into direct MySQL queries, in the hopes of optimizing them further. I see that my initial get_posts query, once built and executed, looks a little like this:

```
    SELECT wp_posts.*
    FROM wp_posts 
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
    ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    WHERE 1=1 
    AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2) )
    AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('news', 'press_release', 'product')
    AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
    GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
    ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

I found that if I remove the `GROUP BY` statement, I do get a nice reduction in execution time, but I'm questioning if I should take it out or not - it's likely added in the statement for a reason.

Not being the expert in SQL, I wouldn't think that the `GROUP BY` statement is doing much, since it's set onto the post IDs, which will always be unique. Though, would be there a case where the `GROUP BY` would be necessary for Wordpress to use?

Comment: Without the `GROUP BY` you could end up with duplicate results e.g. if a post is attached to both `news` and `press_release`

Comment: But given that post_type is an attribute of post_types, a post could not be more than one type - meaning it's maintaining its one-to-one relationship in regards to post_types?

Comment: `post_type` isn't the issue here, it's the join - since the term relationship table has a one-to-many relationship, a post will be in the result as many times as it has terms for the query. Try it - add a post to both `news` and `press_release`, then run the SQL without the `GROUP BY`

Comment: I don't think I follow. Yes, the wp_term_relationships table has a many-to-one-relationship with wp_posts, because I'm looking for a specific value (2), I'm essentially performing a query that can assume it would be a one-to-one relationship, assuming a post cannot have more than one row with the same term_taxonomy_id, I don't see how it could return duplicate wp_posts rows (based on the constraints mentioned above).

Comment: Oh man it's been a long day - just realised `news` etc. are post types and you are indeed querying only one term. Yes you're correct, in this instance the `GROUP BY` is not needed. The reason it's there is because WP does not implement any kind of check to see if it's needed - if it's a tax query, the `GROUP BY` is there, regardless if you're querying for one term or 100.

Comment: Aha, no problem! That makes sense. Good to know that there is a blind add of the GROUP BY when adding a taxonomy condition. If you want, submit it as an answer and I'll accept it :)